# How can I change the color of the text in Firebase UI (Android) country code picker

Tags: android, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase UI 4.0.1 in my app which uses the following theme via `AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)`

```
<style name="Base"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>
</style>

<style name="Base.AppTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Yas_EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Yas_EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>

<style name="LoginTheme" parent="@style/Base">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/Login_AlertDialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Login_AlertDialogStyle" parent="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Note that `primaryTextColor` is white. When I do this, everything looks fine, until I open the alert dialog for the country code picker. There I get a list of countries but the text is white on a white background. I'm trying to get that text to be black, but it's showing white on white. Here's a link to the dialog class that's being called: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/ui/phone/CountryListSpinner.java#L163

How can I make sure that Firebase UI uses my `Login_AlertDialogStyle`?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your FirebaseUI theme:

`<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Login_AlertDialogStyle</item>`

You will first need to create a custom FirebaseUI theme in your `styles.xml`, which must extend from FirebaseUI. Then, you need to set this style via the AuthUI builder:

**Styles.xml**

```
<style name="SignInTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Login_AlertDialogStyle</item>
    <!-- Feel free to add anything else you want here -->
</style>
```

**Activity.class**

```
Intent firebaseAuth = AuthUI.getInstance()
    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
    .setTheme(R.style.SignInTheme) // set your sign in theme here
    .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()))
    .build();
```

More here on customizing the UI: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#ui-customization

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me

```
<style name="FirebaseUI.TextInputEditText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```